# C# SOAP MaxReceivedMessageSize, where to add it?

Tags: c#, soap

I have imported SAP SOAP service from WSDL file and everything is now working fine until the default limits are exceeded.

I get the following error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Normally I would change my app.config file and add the higher limit but it seems not to work.

So where should it be added?

```
QueryMarketingLeadInClient m_SAP_Query = new QueryMarketingLeadInClient("binding");
```

app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="binding_SOAP12">
                    <mtomMessageEncoding />
                    <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="binding">
                    <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
                    <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://sap.adrress.here"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding_SOAP12"
                contract="QueryMarketingLeadIn" name="binding_SOAP12" />
            <endpoint address="https://sap.adrress.here"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding" contract="QueryMarketingLeadIn"
                name="binding" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the anwser to my problem. The thing was that in CustomBinding the app.config settings are different than normal Binding

This post was the key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359548/4845680

Configuration was done in inside binding element using `<httpsTransport>` and `<mtomMessageEncoding>` elements

I have changed my app.config to this

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="binding_SOAP12">
                <mtomMessageEncoding maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                  <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength ="2147483647"/>
                </mtomMessageEncoding>
                <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" maxReceivedMessageSize ="2147483647" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="binding">
                <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                  <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength ="2147483647"/>
                </mtomMessageEncoding>
                <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" maxReceivedMessageSize ="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://sap.adrress.here""
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding_SOAP12"
            contract="QueryMarketingLeadIn" name="binding_SOAP12" />
        <endpoint address="https://sap.adrress.here""
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding" contract="QueryMarketingLeadIn"
            name="binding" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```